# Magento 2 move page main title into div with product_list_toolbar

Tags: magento2, layout, category

I want to move the page main title on the category list page into custom div and also include the `product_list_toolbar` into that div.

The problem I face is that I can not simply move the `product_list_toolbar`, because that is not allowed in M2.

Is there a way to create a div inside the `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` and move the `page.main.title` into that div?

So something like this in the category list template:

```
<div class="category-page-header" id="category.page.header">
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
</div>
```

And then inside the `catalog_catagory_view.xml` file:

```
<move element="page.main.title" destination="category.page.header" before="-"/>
```

Any ideas how to create this div around both elements?

I can solve it by adding the following into the `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` file.

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');?> 

<?= $category->getName() ?>
```

Will this be the best and only solution?